# To show Dec, Jan, Feb as low flow season

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

I have a following dataframe:

```
head(df)
  Sl.no       Date   Year  Month Season  concentration
1     1 1993-12-01  1993   Dec Winter          20.0
2     2 1994-01-01  1994   Jan Winter          21.0
3     3 1994-02-01  1994   Feb Winter          20.0
4     4 1994-03-01  1994   Mar Spring          21.5
5     5 1994-04-01  1994   Apr Spring          29.0
6     6 1994-05-01  1994   May Spring          40.0
```

i want to add a column to the dataframe such that all the Dec, Jan ,Feb, Mar, Apr to show "low flow" and rest of the months to show "High flow".

i tried the following:

```
df$hflf <- if (df$Month==c("Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"))
{"low flow"} else {"high flow"}.
```

but it doesnot seem to work.

how can i achieve this. Your help would be appreciated

Comment: Use `ifelse` with `%in%` i.e. `with(df, ifelse(Month %in% c("Dec", .."Apr"), "low flow", "high flow"))`

Comment: thank you @akrun. i didnt know about ifelse(). It works.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @akrun in comment, you can do:

```
lowflow <- c("Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr")
df$hflf <- ifelse(df$Year %in% lowflow, "low flow", "high flow")
```

With `dplyr` package you can also do:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(hflf2 = case_when(Year %in% lowflow~"low flow", TRUE~"high flow"))
```